# Move list item between folder

Tags: folder, list-item

I try to find solution in SharePoint 2013, how to move list items between folders. I know, that it is possible in SiteManager, but only between lists, not folders. I think, that Powershell should help, but I cannot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it manually using the 'Site Content and Structure' page in site settings.

Comment: Yes I have tried that (SiteManager), but on the list i does not work, bud when i created new test list, it works. So, the list has any problem, but I don't know it.

Comment: I found reason, why it didn't work, it was because there wasn't allowed folders on the list. When the folders was created, anybody cancel possibility to create them and then I couln't open them in Site Content and Structure.

Comment: The "Site Content and Structure" page is available only when SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure is site collection feature is active, [https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/3171513/supported-scenarios-for-site-content-and-structure-in-sharepoint-and-s](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/3171513/supported-scenarios-for-site-content-and-structure-in-sharepoint-and-s).